# Java calculator using switch case

Tags: java, calculator

My requirement - `calc` method should take two numbers from `main`, and `calc` will perform all the operations. Everything goes fine until a problem occurs in `switch` command. I get the error "choice cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learn {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int firstnumber, secondnumber, choice;

        System.out.println("1- Add");
        System.out.println("2- Sub");
        System.out.println("3- Div");
        System.out.println("4- Mul");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice -");
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);

        choice = var.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter first number -");
        firstnumber = var.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number -");
        secondnumber = var.nextInt();
        calc(firstnumber, secondnumber);
    }

    public static void calc(int x, int y) {
        int c;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                c = x + y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 2:
                c = x - y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 3:
                c = x / y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 4:
                c = x * y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing, and how can I fix this?

Comment: `choice` is a **local** variable in `main`...

Comment: Code in one function can't see local variables in another function.

Comment: remember that when posting code in a question, all your code needs to be indented by 4 spaces. You didn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Since `choice` is a local in a different function, you need to pass it as a parameter:

```
public static void calc(int x, int y, int choice) {
    ...
}
...
calc (firstnumber,secondnumber, choice);
```

Note that your `calc` method is not optimal: all four `case`s have the same line in them:

```
System.out.print("Output-" + c);
```

You could move this line to after the `switch`, and add a default case to throw an exception when the choice is invalid.

Comment: Agreed on factoring out that common statement from all the `case` blocks.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass `choice` as an argument to `calc` if you wish to use its value in `calc` - something like this tweak to your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learn {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int firstnumber, secondnumber, choice;

        System.out.println("1- Add");
        System.out.println("2- Sub");
        System.out.println("3- Div");
        System.out.println("4- Mul");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice -");
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);

        choice = var.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter first number -");
        firstnumber = var.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number -");
        secondnumber = var.nextInt();
        calc(choice, firstnumber, secondnumber); // 3rd arg added for choice
    }

    public static void calc(int choice, int x, int y) { // 3rd param added for choice
        int c;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                c = x + y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 2:
                c = x - y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 3:
                c = x / y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;

            case 4:
                c = x * y;
                System.out.print("Output-" + c);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```